# What happens when a probability actually occurs?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Sorry if I am mixing up the model with the reality, but when for instance a low probability occurs, what happens with the rest of the probability? Philosophically I find it hard to argue that any other probability than 1 has occured.

For instance, 80 % probability will likely occur. When it occurs, what hapened to the rest, 20 %, if all probability did exist as physical matter like in quantum physics where we model matter as a probability space.

Comment: This answer would be unreasonably long, as it would have to cover both the philosophical arguments of probability as well as the quantum ones. Even either of those two would be too broad - is there a way for you to narrow the scope of this question a bit?

Comment: The statement changes from "the probability that $X$ will occur is $.8$" to "the probability that $X$ has occurred is $1$".

Comment: +1, awesome question, all these years never realised to wonder about this!

Comment: this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1RzvXDXyqA should be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Law of Conservation of Probability: If $\Pr(A)=0.8$ then $\Pr(A^c)=0.2$. Here $A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$, the event that $A$ *doesn't* occur.

Answer (score 2):

Probability is not a conserved quantity. It is always estimated on the basis of a given state of information. When that information is updated, the probability will generally change.